# How do I print my seaborn plot to a tkinter window, will show in IDE but doesnt stick to canvas

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, canvas, seaborn

I have:

```
def create_plot(): 

    df = pd.read_json("my_final_data.json")

    small_df = df[df.small_airport.isin(['Y'])]
    medium_df = df[df.medium_airport.isin(['Y'])]
    large_df = df[df.large_airport.isin(['Y'])] 

    plt.figure(figsize=(35,10))
    ax = sns.distplot(small_df['frequency_mhz'], color='red', label='Small Airports')
    sns.distplot(medium_df['frequency_mhz'], color='green', ax=ax, label='Medium Airports')
    sns.distplot(large_df['frequency_mhz'], ax=ax, label='Large Airports')
    plt.legend(loc="upper right")

    graph = plt.show()

    return graph


#Generating tkinter window
window1 = tk.Tk()
figure = create_plot()
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, master=window1)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
tk.mainloop()
```

Which launches 2(?) empty tkinter windows besides the canvas in one, but the IDE shows the actual graph im trying to print so I know the function is doing its job.

How do I make that returned graph stick to the window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Youre getting 2 empty windows because you used `plt.show()` which is not intended to be used from within a tkinter application. The other one is an empty tkinter window (generated via `tk.Tk()`), without any content.
- You also missed to give us sample data (`my_final_data.json`).
- A little bit of research would have brought you a lot of examples for seaborn integration into tkinter
- `sns.distplot` is deprecated as mentioned [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html), i would recommend using `sns.displot` or `sns.histplot` instead ([some nice histplot examples](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html#seaborn.histplot))

This example should get you started:

```
import tkinter as tk
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk


def create_plot(root):
    # create random seaborn displot; replace this part with your own data
    figure, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6))
    penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
    sns.histplot(data=penguins, x="flipper_length_mm", ax=ax, hue="species")

    # create tkinter canvas from figure
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, master=root)
    canvas.draw()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

    # optional: create toolbar
    toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, root)
    toolbar.update()
    canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)


# create your application
window1 = tk.Tk()

# call function to create plot
create_plot(window1)

# mainloop
tk.mainloop()
```